# Array JSON in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, jsp

My json is:

```
[
   {
      "_id":{
         "time":1381823399000,
         "new":false,
         "timeSecond":1381823399,
         "machine":263168773,
         "inc":-649466399
      },
      "asset":"RO2550AS1",
      "Salt Rejection":"90%",
      "Salt Passage":"10%",
      "Recovery":"59%",
      "Concentration Factor":"2.43",
      "status":"critical",
      "Flow Alarm":"High Flow"
   },
   [
      {
         "Estimated Cost":"USD 15",
         "AssetName":"RO2500AS1",
         "Description":"Pump Maintenance",
         "Index":"1",
         "Type":"Service",
         "DeadLine":"13 November 2013"
      },
      {
         "Estimated Cost":"USD 35",
         "AssetName":"RO2500AS1",
         "Description":"Heat Sensor",
         "Index":"2",
         "Type":"Replacement",
         "DeadLine":"26 November 2013"
      },
      {
         "Estimated Cost":"USD 35",
         "AssetName":"RO2550AS1",
         "Description":"Heat Sensor",
         "Index":"3",
         "Type":"Replacement",
         "DeadLine":"26 November 2013"
      },
      {
         "Estimated Cost":"USD 15",
         "AssetName":"RO2550AS1",
         "Description":"Pump Maintenance",
         "Index":"4",
         "Type":"Service",
         "DeadLine":"13 November 2013"
      },
      {
         "Estimated Cost":"USD 15",
         "AssetName":"RO3000AS1",
         "Description":"Pump Maintenance",
         "Index":"5",
         "Type":"Service",
         "DeadLine":"13 November 2013"
      },
      {
         "Estimated Cost":"USD 35",
         "AssetName":"RO3000AS1",
         "Description":"Heat Sensor",
         "Index":"6",
         "Type":"Replacement",
         "DeadLine":"26 November 2013"
      }
   ]
]
```

I need to access it in javascript.

The following code is not working:

```
var jsonobjstr = JSON.parse(jsonOutput);
alert ("asset: "+jsonobjstr.asset);
```

Comment: What is `jsonOutput` set to? Do you have any error messages appearing in the _console_?

Comment: This has nothing to do with "java", tag removed.

Comment: Hint: you are passing Json inside of an array, treat it as such

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript

`var somename = [];` means a new array and;
`var somename = {};` means a new object.

Therefore if some json starts with a `[]` means it is a array of objects, and if it starts with {} means it is a object.

Your json starts with `[]`, therefore it is a array of objects, so you need to access each object by doing:

`json[n].asset` for each position of the array (where n is a integer).

BUT:

Your JSON is weird. Looks like you will always have a array with one element (if true, the json should start with `{}`.

LIKE:

```
{
    "id":
    {
        "code":1381823399000
    },
    "asset":"RO2550AS1",
    "history":
    [
        {
            "value":"USD 15"
        },
        {
            "value":"USD 15"
        },
        {
            "value":"USD 15"
        }
    ]
 }
```

Here you can do:

```
thing.id.code
thing.asset
thing.history[0].value
thing.history[1].value
```

Comment: I disagree with your *BUT*: He's passing an array with 1 object followed by another array of objects containing uniform information.

Comment: There is nothing to disagree. If the parent object is not an array, why treat it like so? Look at the example.

Comment: Of course there is something to disagree. Your statement did not say anything at all about "wrapping" the uniform information in a separate property prior to your edit. Without the example to clarify your intention, your statement is simply false, or perhaps incomplete. Regardless, debates are against the rules.

Answer (score 4):

Because the entire `JSON` is contained in an array.

```
alert("asset: "+jsonobjstr[0].asset);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/yHj5X/2/